# Removing error messages if input is valid using an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form with server side validation using codeigniter built-in helper. I'm using ajax for sending data in my controller. It returns a json response which I am using in success function.

Here's the controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->validates()['create']);
       if($this->form_validation->run()){
           $response['status'] = true;
           $response['message'] = "Successfully added user";
           $response['page'] = base_url('/user');
           $this->user_model->user_add($this->form_input()['create']);
       }else{
           $errors = array();
           foreach ($this->input->post() as $key => $value) {
               $errors[$key] = form_error($key);
           }
           $response['errors'] = array_filter($errors);
           $response['status'] = false;
       }
    $this->jsonresponse($response);
```

Here's the ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:site_url('user/user_add'),
        data: $('#user_form').serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log('test');
        },
        success: function(response){
           if(response.status == true){
                alert(response.message);
           }else{
            $.each(response.errors,function(key,val){
                var names = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","username","job"];
                if(names.indexOf(key) > -1){

                     $('input[name="' + key + '"]').next().html(val);
                }else{
                    $('input[name="' + key + '"]').next().html('');
                }
            });

       }
        }
    });
```

Here's the view:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
        <div class="row container-fluid well" style="background: white; border:3px groove orange;">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                <table id="patient_data" class="table display row-border table-condensed" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Middle Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Birthdate</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Bloodtype</th>
                        <th>Height</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="patient_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="patient_form" autocomplete="off">
                  <div class="row">
                  <input type="text" name="id" hidden>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Middle Name</label>
                            <input type=    "text" class="form-control" name="middlename">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">


                            <label for="firstname">Gender</label>
                            <div class="form-check">

                                <label for="gender" class="radio-inline" style="padding-right: 20px;">

                                    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">

                                    Female 
                                </label>
                                <label for="gender" class="radio-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
                                    Male
                                </label>
                                 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="" hidden checked>
                               <span class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="firstname">Birthdate</label>
                                <input type="date" id="birthdate" class="form-control" name="birthdate">
                                <span class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="firstname">Age</label>
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="age">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Height (cm)</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control" name="height" class="extra">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Weight (kg)</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control" name="weight" class="extra">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Blood Type</label>
                            <select name="bloodtype" class="form-control">
                                <option hidden selected></option>
                                <option value="A-">Blood Type A - Negative</option>
                                <option value="A+">Blood Type A - Positive</option>
                                <option value="B-">Blood Type B - Negative</option>
                                <option value="B+">Blood Type B - Positive</option>
                                <option value="AB-">Blood Type AB - Negative </option>
                                <option value="AB+">Blood Type AB - Positive</option>
                                <option value="O-">Blood Type O - Negative</option>
                                <option value="O+">Blood Type O - Positive </option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Address</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstname">Contact Number</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="11" class="form-control" name="contact">
                            <span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>    
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-push-10 btn-sm submit" id="patient_action" type="button"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I check if the response status from the controller is success or fail. If fail it will iterate the response errors then display it.

My problem is if a field is already valid it will not hide or remove. I use array with field names on it to checked if it contains the same as the response errors but it is not working.

Form validation is working and jsonresponse is a function in my MY_Controller which returns an json encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this documentation for the set rule for validation
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

```
//$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->validates()['create']);
```

if you set rule properly then change following in your code

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
   $response['status'] = true;
   $response['message'] = "Successfully added user";
   $response['page'] = base_url('/user');
   $this->user_model->user_add($this->form_input()['create']);
}else{
   $response['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();//generate error array with input post key
   $response['status'] = false;
}
//set page header in JSON format
$this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

change your success callback of Ajax

```
success: function(response){
  //remove all errors
  $('#patient_form .form-group').find('span.text-danger').text('');
  if(response.status == true){
      alert(response.message);
  }else{
    var names = ["firstname","middlename","lastname","username","job"];
    //appent all errors 1-1
    $.each(response.errors,function(key,val){
      if(names.indexOf(key) > -1){
        $('#patient_form input[name="'+key+'"]').parent('.form-group').children('span.text-danger').text(val);
      }
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: form validation or the json encoding is not the problem but how to remove error messages if the field is valid.

Comment: @RicardoRaz please check updated code, If still getting an error in the console then Plz send the **response** of Ajax.

Comment: its gotten worse, form errors now cannot be seen in the form. I am not getting an error in the console.

Comment: @RicardoRaz what you getting in response..?